# Spring security Oauth - redirection to client app

Tags: spring, angular, spring-security-oauth2

I was creaded api with spring that is secured by Oauth2. Configuration file for facebook looks like below

```
clientId: xxx
clientSecret: xxxx
accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
tokenName: oauth_token
scope: email
authenticationScheme: query
clientAuthenticationScheme: form
registeredRedirectUri: http://apitest.com:8080/login
```

after successful `authentication redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/");` is executed.

On client site I'm using angular2. Problem is when I redirect user to facebook login form, then I don't know how to redirect user back to Angular2 app instead of "http://my-api-domain.loc/".

What is the best practice how can I do this.

Comment: When   calling your   oauth2  `authorize` endpoint you should sent `redirect_url` parameter to api.In this case it redirect user to spring security login page and user needs to enter his creditionals.After successful login api will  redirect to your client application(angular2)  and you should call `token` endpoint of oauth2 api and you will get  bareer token and now you can request secured resource with your `access_token`.

Comment: When you do test you may for need to clear cookies from your browser  or you can test with incognito mode

Answer (score 1):

Most common is that facebook has a redirect url to navigate to after login.
Eventually it is stored with your api key (facebook app) or you can add it as separate url parameter with the login.

I think with facebook it is the first with the stored url at your facebook app.